# How can I create a modal list of values using just bootstrap and angular with springboot as a backend?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a generic "List of Values", a searchable modal with a natural identifier and a description. I have managed to create an angularjs app that does this in SpringBoot but it is not callable as a modal.

I want to use nothing but angularjs, bootstrap and springboot mvc, I don't want to get into node as the backend.

I attempted to follow the instructions here:

https://www.uibootstrap.net/angular-ui-bootstrap/angular-bootstrap-modal-example-demo/

But they are incomplete, code fragments.  I have tried to put it all together and have the following three files:

At this point I am getting

Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module TestApp due to:

[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.bootstrap due to:

[$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.bootstrap' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

I don't even know where this would get ui.bootstrap and the installation instructions for it say to use npm, I want to know what files are being used and place them in my springboot project.  Npm and node are not in the architectural plans.

index.html:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Model</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.js"></script>
<script src="./app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="TestApp">
        <div class="well">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="openModal()">Click
                to Open Modal Window!</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

app.js:

```
var modalInstance = '';

var app = angular.module('TestApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    function modalOpenCtrl($scope, payload){
        console.log('fgfdfd');
        $scope.datas = payload;
        console.log($scope.datas);
        $scope.closeModal = function(){
            $scope.cancelModal();
        }
    }

    $scope.openModal = function(task){
        modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            animation: false,
            templateUrl: './modal_window.html',
            controller: 'modalOpenCtrl',
            scope: $scope,
            size: 'md',
            backdrop: 'static',
            resolve: {
                payload: function () {
                    return {
                        msg_body : 'Hello! I am payload msg',
                        title : 'Hello! Title',
                        body_title : 'UiBootstrap.net'
                    };
                }
            }
        });
    }

    function modalOpenCtrl($scope, payload){
        console.log('fgfdfd');
        $scope.datas = payload;
        console.log($scope.datas);
        $scope.closeModal = function(){
            $scope.cancelModal();
        }
    }
})
```

modal_window.html:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Model</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.js"></script>
<script>
    src="./app.js"
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
            aria-label="Close" ng-click="closeModal()">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <div class="modal-title">
            <h4>{{datas.title}}</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body log-view">
        <div class="clearfix">
            <h2>{{datas.body_title}}</h2>
            <div>{{datas.msg_body}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer model-grey-color">

        <div class="clearfix">
            <div>
                <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="closeModal()">
                    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-ok"></i> Ok
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="closeModal()">
                    <i class="fa fa-close"></i> Close
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you haven't connected linking between controller and view

The error `Failed to instantiate module ui.bootstrap due to:` you are getting due to it's not loaded and you are trying to use this module.

Please check below for how to show modal using ui.bootstrap

First you need to create proper directory structure in order to load files when application run in browser.

Directory structure example:

[image]

Now let's jump to index.html

1. index.html:

   ```
   <html>
   <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
       <title>Model</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
   </head>
   <body>
       <div ng-app="TestApp" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
           <div class="well">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="openModal('abc')">Click
                   to Open Modal Window!</button>
           </div>
       </div>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.js"></script>
       <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.3.js"></script>
       <script src="js/app.js"></script>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
2. app.js

   ```
   var modalInstance = '';

   var app = angular.module('TestApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
   app.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope, $http,$uibModal) {

       $scope.modalOpenCtrl = function($scope, payload){
           console.log('fgfdfd');
           $scope.datas = payload;
           console.log($scope.datas);
           $scope.closeModal = function(){
               console.log("this is close modal")
               $scope.cancelModal();
           }
       }

       $scope.openModal = function(task){
           modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
               animation: false,
               templateUrl: './main_window.html',
               controller: 'modalOpenCtrl',
               scope: $scope,
               size: 'md',
               backdrop: 'static',
               resolve: {
                   payload: function () {
                       return {
                           msg_body : 'Hello! I am payload msg',
                           title : 'Hello! Title',
                           body_title : 'UiBootstrap.net'
                       };
                   }
               }
           });
       }

       $scope.cancelModal = function(){
           console.log("this is final called");
           modalInstance.close();
       }

   });
   ```
3. main_window.html

   ```
   <div>
       <div class="modal-header">
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
               aria-label="Close" ng-click="closeModal()">
               <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
           </button>
           <div class="modal-title">
               <h4>{{datas.title}}</h4>
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body log-view">
           <div class="clearfix">
               <h2>{{datas.body_title}}</h2>
               <div>{{datas.msg_body}}</div>
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-footer model-grey-color">

           <div class="clearfix">
               <div>
                   <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="closeModal()">
                       <i class="ace-icon fa fa-ok"></i> Ok
                   </button>
                   <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="closeModal()">
                       <i class="fa fa-close"></i> Close
                   </button>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```

That's it run this code and it will be open modal on button click

**Note: This is just basic setup of angularjs. We can still improve this code if you have more features to built like routing, api calls, mvc pattern**

Here is [medium](https://medium.com/@blondiebytes/learn-the-basics-of-angular-js-17523690594e) blog which explains some basics features of angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add bootstrap script to your index.html file like `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>`